# Adjusting the height of rows 3 and to the bottom of the sheet (where the # of rows in the sheet is constantly changing) [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

What I am trying to achieve:

- I have a checkbox in cell C1.
- When it is checked, I want to adjust the row height of rows 3 and down to the bottom of the sheet so that they autoresize to 'fit to data'.
- When unchecked, I want to adjust the row height of rows 3 and down to the bottom of the sheet to 21.

This does not happen. Can anyone give advice as to why?

My script:

```
function onEdit(e)  {

 // This if-statement ensures the macro only runs when the checkbox in cell C1 is used.
 if (
   e.source.getSheetName() == "Meals" &&
   e.range.getColumn() == 3 &&
   e.range.getRow() == 1
 ) { 

   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var Meals = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Meals");
   var LastRow = Meals.getLastRow();

   var checkboxtest = e.range.getValue()     // This variable is used in the if-statement below, to see if the checkbox was checked or unchecked.

   if (checkboxtest == true) {               // If checkbox is checked...
     Meals.autoResizeRows(3, LastRow-2);     // set the row heights to auto-adjust.
   }else{                                    // If checkbox is unchecked...
     Meals.setRowHeights(3, LastRow-2, 21);  // set the row heights equal to 21.
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: When asking a question, describe the problem. Your post doesn't even pose a question.

Comment: There seems to be an issue and it may be (related to) this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121054553). When using setRowHeight from a script row height won't accept a value lower than that of the auto-resize height. I'd like to see a workaround or to find out I was wrong. :-)

Comment: @TheMaster, please see the updated post. I tried to make it clearer but other than that I am not sure what else I can add? Any further feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: @ADW I see! It appears that may indeed be the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Specifically,1. Describe: "When I check the checkbox, nothing  happens" <= It shows that what was expected to happen did not.  This is important. 2.  Trying to find the problem: "I looked into script editor>view> executions to see if I can find any error logs. The logs show execution did happen at the time, I clicked the checkbox and that it executed successfully-no errors were logged". 3. Any attempts you made to solve the problem+research: "I tried different sheets, autoResizeRow without the checkbox/onEdit, but by directly running from the script editor: it seems resize doesn't work at all"

Comment: See [mcve].....

Answer (score 1):

- When the checkbox at the cell "C1" is checked, you want to run the auto resize of the row height from row 3 to the bottom row.
- When the checkbox at the cell "C1" is unchecked, you want to set the row height to 21 pixels from row 3 to the bottom row.
- You want to run the script when the checkbox is changed.

### Issue and workaround:

In this case, when the Spreadsheet service is used, the auto resize of the rows can be done. But unfortunately, `setRowHeights()` cannot be used for this situation. I also think that this is due to a bug as mentioned by [ADW's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61072893/adjusting-the-height-of-rows-3-and-to-the-bottom-of-the-sheet-where-the-of-ro#comment108047080_61072893).

So in this answer, as a workaround, I would like to propose to use the batchUpdate method of Sheets API for achieving your goal.

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

### Usage:

1. Please modify your script as follows.
2. Before you use this script, [please install the installable OnEdit event trigger to the function of `installedOnEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) which was modified. Because Sheets API cannot be used with the simple trigger.
3. [Please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).
4. As a test, please uncheck the checkbox of cell "C1".

### Modified script:

#### From:

```
function onEdit(e)  {
```

#### To:

```
function installedOnEdit(e)  {
```

And

#### From:

```
Meals.setRowHeights(3, LastRow-2, 21);
```

#### To:

```
const requests = {updateDimensionProperties: {
  properties: {pixelSize: 21},
  range: {dimension: "ROWS", sheetId: Meals.getSheetId(), startIndex: 2},
  fields: "pixelSize"
}};
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, spreadsheet.getId());
```

- After the function of `installedOnEdit` was installed and Sheets API was enabled, when the checkbox is unchecked, the row height is changed to 21 pixels.

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request?hl=ja#updatedimensionpropertiesrequest)

Comment: @Nagaram92 I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56297960/7108653). Although this doesn't use the event trigger, I think that this might be also useful for your situation.